# Access Class in Class Variable

Tags: php

I have this code:

```
class A
{
 public $db
}

class B
{
 public $cssA 

 public function __construct()
 {
  $this->cssA = new A();
 }
}
```

The question is, how can I call a method in `class B` from `class A`?

Comment: I don't understand the question at the end, could you rephrase it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't as there is no reference to the object of class `B`.

```
class A {
   public $db;

   private $b;

   public function __construct(B $b) {
       $this->b = $b;
   }
}

class B {
   private $a;

   public function __construct() {
       $this->a = new A($this);
   }
}
```

Methods of object of class `B` can be now accessed through `$this->b->doSomething()` within object of class `A`.

Comment: This will create a copy of $this on the `class A`-object, which is impreferable. You can better use 'pass-by-reference' instead, so `$this->a = new A(&$this);`. I know this is not PHP's best aspect, but it's the best way to go about this in this case.

Comment: Objects are always passed-by-reference in PHP5+.

Comment: Not a total reference, but good enough for the example (and BTW: even scalars/non-objects are only copied under the hood if you change one of them, until then PHP will just let multiple varnames point to the same value in memory, test: `'$a=5;$b=$a;debug_zval_dump($a);debug_zval_dump($b);$a=6;debug_zval_dump($b);debug_zval_dump($a);`)

Comment: @Kilzone that's only in PHP4 OOP, which this is not compatible with. The use of the magic method __construct(), access levels (public/protected/private) indicates that this is PHP5 OOP in use.

Comment: You're right, ignore my comment, my mistake. I've not done this construction for quite some time (usually use the same technique as CodeIgniter implements, got it from studying their code), so a little out of practise, again my appologies.

Answer (score -1):

You would have to instantiate class b within class a and then call the method...

```
$this->aProp = new A();
$this->aProp->classAfunction();
$aVal = $this->aProp->publicProperty;
```

Basic oo programming stuff.

Comment: your code snippet lacks context for `$this` -- is it supposed to be in class A? class B? You don't say directly, which will confuse those new to OO design.

Comment: The question sets up the context for the answer to your comment.  The question specifically states that he wants to access class a methods from class b; so, the location of this code should be in class b based on such context.